# Edit Properties of MKV Files

Tags: c#, video, metadata

I'd like to apply some consistent naming conventions for the various tracks in my MKV files and edit some of the other metadata properties.  Currently, I'm using the Header Editor in MKVTOOLNIX to accomplish this task, one file at a time, but I'm looking for a programmatic solution I can design in a C# solution that I can then apply to batches of files.

In particular, I want to be able to programmatically edit the following:

1. Video track

   - Name property (eg Amadeus (1984) )
   - Default Track Flag property (eg True)
2. All Audio Tracks

   - Name property (eg Dolby Digital 5.1)
   - Default Track Flag property (eg True/False)
3. All Subtitle Tracks

   - Name property (eg English-PGS)

I tried using the TagLib library for this purpose, but it either doesn't offer access to these particular properties or I couldn't find how to access them using their API.

Any suggestions on how to programmatically edit the properties listed above would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use the MKVTOOLNIX and call them from my application

Comment: Hi Sir Rufo, are you saying you can programmatically control MKVTOOLNIX from a C# solution?  If so, do you have any more info on this?

Comment: Sure, search for Process.Start

Comment: Now I see what you're saying, that won't work.  Process.Start is just a simple .Net method used to start a program.  I'm looking for a tool/API to  programmatically execute commands that will update specific properties of a MKV video file.